# ANDROID_HOME varibale changed to PWD

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, android-sdk

I want to setup Android SDK on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS for React Native programming. 
according to the [official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#3-configure-the-android-home-environment-variable) I have to define paths in `.bash_profile`.
at first I was just putting the `export` commands i n terminal which seems it is not permanent and on each logout they disappear. 
but I defined them in `.bashrc` and I could see all via `printenv | grep Android`.
now I moved them to `.bash_profile` so the file looks like

```
    # Android Paths    
    export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

but now on `printenv` I get

```
PWD=/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools
OLDPWD=/home/user/Android/Sdk
```

As I am new in Ubuntu I have got totally confused what and where is the correct place to identify the environment variables?

Comment: `PWD` and `OLDPWD` are set dynamically and have nothing to do with the variables you set in `~/.bash_profile`. But probably `~/.profile` would be a more appropriate place to set them.

Comment: `PWD` is Present Working Directory that you are currently in, and `OLDPWD` is the folder you were in before you switched to that directory.